# How trigger one flow for all lists in my site

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Good morning,

I am looking for a way to create one flow that handle all creation and update event in all my lists, in other words I want to create on flow that have a trigger "When an Item is created or updated" not only for a specified list, but for all my lists in my site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One Flow to handle them all - how to subscribe to multiple SharePoint lists with one Flow for your reference:

http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/3/one-flow-to-handle-them-all-how-to-subscribe-to-multiple-sharepoint-lists-with-one-flow

Create a trigger on multiple SharePoint lists for your reference:

https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/04/17/microsoft-flow-create-a-trigger-on-multiple-sharepoint-lists-sharepoint-designer-workflows-cant-do-this/

Comment: I couldn't understand it, any more clarification ?